# How do you fix a sloped residual plot in OLS simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, least-squares

I am building a simple OLS model with form `Y = b0 + b1X`

I have a residual plot that looks like this.  It seems like if we were to decrease the coefficient (`b1`) of the independent variable, we could almost fit it perfectly.

[image]

Yet that is what OLS returns.   I'd imagine the reason for this is because the conditional distribution of Y given X is not normal and similarly how outliers can pull the regression line away, extra data points in one area may be pulling the curve here.

What would be the solutions in such a scenario? Transformations?  Are there other models that may solve this?

Edit With Hexplot and smaller marker size:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in interpretation or just predicting/fit?

Comment: A bit of both?  I'm looking to predict Y, but it's important to capture how Y changes when X changes.  I guess having a good looking residual plot is more important, even if on average, the prediction may be a bit off because the distribution is skewed.

Comment: The plot is almost useless due to the huge amount of overplotting of points.  Redo it as a hexbin plot or with transparency or with much smaller points.

Comment: Is your response bounded?

Comment: Yes both response and independent variable are bounded between 0 and 1.  I did some minor transformations before hand to so the X, Y scatter plot itself looked linear and then built a model.  I'll recreate the plot.  I'd imagine the point around (0,0) is where most of the observations are.

Comment: Would sampling from the area with high density make sense?  Not sure if there's a mathematical way to do this so that conditional distribution is normalish on average for all X values.

Comment: Or maybe a dummy.  A dummy should just adjust the intercept so we shift the mean in that area, letting the rest of the observations fit properly if my intuition is correct.  Since slope seems to be the same in all areas, we also wouldn't need interaction terms.

Comment: Ok dummy doesn't work.

Comment: What are the residuals plotted against? $X$?

Answer (score 2):

You should fit a LOESS smooth.

A "slanted" residual plot like this typically results from the influence of a few VERY influential and VERY leveraging observations (aka outliers). I might even venture to ask whether your plot axes have truncated any values with $X>1$. But there might be another explanation.

Another option is that in the very, very small range of $X$ (i.e. $x<0.1$), you have SUCH a density of observations, the trend is dominated by the local trend. Since the point cloud is so intense, and the range is so small, we can't be sure, but the marginal histograms show quite a large density of observations at this point. The corresponding residual plot, with center-filled observations, destroy our hope of visualizing the actual density of residuals within this range.

A LOESS smooth might show a "hockey-stick" shaped trendline closely following the model results in the range of $0<x<0.1$ and then a trend line that turns down somewhat. If the residual plot used non-filled points like in R, you might be able to see the same hockey-stick shape.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes it's the latter where one area is so dense minimizing error just leads to minimizing error of that area.  What if I create a dummy for that area?

Comment: @confused A dummy will not allow the slope to change, it will just create a breakpoint. Draw the fitted trend to convince yourself. A dummy and interaction with X will have a breakpoint and line change, which may or may not make sense if a discontinuity is actually expected. The last option is to just add the product term for the dummy and the time variable. This is a 1st degree spline with a single "knot" at that point, what I'm referring to as a hockey stick.

Comment: I'll try the LOESS.  I just tried a dummy and yes you are right, slope didn't change.  It just shifted the residuals there up.

Answer (score 0):

A comment requiring clarification:
The data in your residual plot looks more like a box instead of a cloud. Is there a reason to believe that data has been truncated? If so, when the data is truncated, what do you obtain?
The data in your residual plot has "inner clouds". Are there other factors that you have information about?

Answers to your questions
What would be the solutions in such a scenario?
Indeed, transformation help to spread the data distribution. Though, you would lose the linear relation.
An idea, to practically implement the density graph you have also shown, would be to slice the data in X at non-uniform intervals. For example, every interval contains n contiguous points. For each slice calculate the average, and use these new points for your linear regression. To determine a reasonable amount of point, plot the standard deviation of the residuals vs the amount of points used.

Are there other models that may solve this?
I would use a SVM with a circular kernel to create two groups, therefore separating the points at x=0 (group 0) from all others (group 1). From group 0 you establish b0 and the noise that can be expected from group 1 you can obtain your b1.